# 3d models path in django using three js

Tags: django

Hi anyone knows about what is the correct way of giving 3d model path in django. Like in which folder i have to put my 3d model. Btw i am using three js.

Error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> 3D Model </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/cona.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="cona"> </canvas>
    <script src="{% static 'js/three.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/OrbitControls.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/GLTFLoader.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/donutCopy.js' %}"></script>

    <script >
        var icing="{% static 'INO.glb'%}"
    </script>

</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you have any progress on the question?